# PyMongo: How to read first n items from the Cursor?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

What's the correct way to read the `n` first items from a PyMongo Cursor? (CommandCursor)

Of course one possible way is just to iterate the cursor but I was wondering if there's a dedicated way to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit()` where n is the number of items to retrieve:

```
cursor = db.mycollection.find().limit(n)
```